# Nesting sum with linq, int does not contain Sum

Tags: c#, linq

The following nested line gives an error but I don't really understand what is wrong. I'm coding in C#. If I look at other examples this should do the trick but unfortunately it doesn't.

```
var PupilsAmount= entities.Reservation.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.AmountOfAttendants= 2.Sum(x => x.PupilsAmount));
```

So I want to give the sum of the value PupilsAmount only for the records where the attendants amount = 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by `2.Sum` ? are you checking for `x.AmountOfAttendants == Sum of x.PupilsAmount` ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is because you're calling `Sum` on the value `2`. `Sum` is an extension method that operates on `IEnumerable<T>` (e.g. some sort of collection), not on an `int`.

Based on your edit, what you're after is:

```
var PupilsAmount= entities.Reservation.AsEnumerable().Where(x=>x.AmountOfAttendants==2).Sum(x=>x.PupilsAmount);
```

What's happening in my modification is a two-stage process:

1. First, I filter the list using `Where`, to get only the records where `AmountOfAttendants` is equal to 2
2. Then, I sum `PupilsAmount` for the remaining records.

Comment: Ok this is what I needed to know I think, need to wait 5mins before I can approve your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the extra adjustement! Went a bit too fast over linq, thought I could already do more then in reality :p